# Editing a file in Bourne Shell

Tags: grep, sh

I'm working on building a student database in Bourne Shell Script. I need to be able to update a line of data that's been previously entered into the file, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. This is what I've tried:

```
   echo "please enter the name: \c"
   read updateInput

   updateNumber=$(grep -cwi $updateInput database.txt)

   if [ "$updateNumber" -gt "1" ]
   then
          echo "ambiguous input"
   elif [ ! grep -iq "$updateInput" database.txt ]
   then
           echo "record not found"
   else
           lineNumber=$(grep -ni $updateInput database.txt)

           grep -i $updateInput database.txt > tmp
           read first last age course1 course2 < tmp

           echo "record found, enter new value now:"
           echo "name ($first $last): \c" 
           read first last
           echo "age ($age): \c"
           read age
           echo "course-1 ($course1): \c"
           read course1
           while ! fgrep -iwq "$course1" $FILE 
           do
                   echo "course does not exist"
                   echo "course-1: \c"
                   read course1  
           done
           echo "course-2 ($course2): \c"
           read course2
           while ! fgrep -iwq "$course2" $FILE 
           do
                   echo "course does not exist"
                   echo "course-2: \c"
                   read course2  
           done
   fi
```

But that's obviously not updating the file at all. I'm just not sure how to take a specific line and change the data of it.

Also, my elif statement doesn't work, and I was wondering what I was doing wrong with that -.- It's just supposed to say, if the name entered isn't found, then print out that the record wasn't found.

Thanks everyone. I'm super new with Bourne Shell Script and I've had some real trouble trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very clear, if you want to update a line in a file. You can use the command "sed", it performs a find/replace into a file. Please check its unix man for the usage.

i.e:

```
sed -i 's/day/night/g' file.txt
```

will replace "day" by "night" in file.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sed` command with the inplace flag `-i` — it is much easier to use than `ed`. For instance, if you want to change the 5-th line of the file by `$first|$last|$course` then do

```
sed -i '' -e s "5s/.*/$first|$last|$course/" database.txt
```

As a side note, you can use `awk` to easily extract data and build reports from your database.